# Modelling EUR/USD with Ornstein-Uhlenbeck + jumps?

Tags: stochastic-processes, modeling, brownian-motion, sde, differential-equations

I'm trying to simulate a process as close as possible to EUR/USD of the ten past years.

I've used a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:

$$d X_t = -\theta (X_t - \mu) d t + \sigma d B_t$$

with the parameters $\mu$, $X_0$, $\theta$, $\sigma$ being calibrated such that mean, standard deviation, total absolute variation (i.e. $\sum_i |X_{t_{i+1}} - X_{t_i}|$ for a given sampling rate) are as close as possible to the *real historical data*. For example I used $\mu \approx$ 1.3 $ / 1 €.

**The only thing that fails is that the created process doesn't have big spikes** whereas the real historical data sometimes shows such jumps.

More precisely, here is the histogram of the **range over 2 hours** (each $X_t$ represents one minute, so 120 means 2 hours):
$$range_t = \max_{k \leq 120} X_{t-k} - \min_{k \leq 120} X_{t-k}$$

[image]

## Question:

**The simulated O-U process I did is too "nice and gentle": the range in 2 hours never exceeds 100 pips, whereas in real-life, the range in 2 hours can exceed 100 pips. How to make it more like the real data?**

How should I improve the model (i.e. the Stochastic Differential Equation) to have more "big ranges"? Add some "jump diffusion" (with which method)? Make $\sigma$ vary, and how?

---

**EDIT**: I tried to add a "jump" term $d\, q_t$ to the SDE, i.e. very rarely we have a "jump" of height $h$ pips, with $h \sim \pm 0.0060 \cdot Log\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, i.e. a "jump" of average height 60 pips (with random sign + or -).

This has an effect of having a heavier tail for the "2hours range" distribution:

[image]

but even by choosing the right parameters, the "heavier tail" still doesn't look like the real EURUSD "2 hours range" histogram tail...

*Another option: Should I replace $d\, B_t$, which is a $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$ by another random variable with a higher kurtosis? Which one?*

Comment: My wild guess is $\sigma$ varies over time, and the 2 hour ranges exceed 100 pips when volatility is elevated (2007-2008 for example). In other words a GARCH effect may be present.

Comment: Thanks @AlexC. I added a question at the end: how should I improve the SDE to allow such behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried using a Student-t or another fat tailed distribution instead of the Normal?

Comment: @Kiwiakos Not yet, I will try it! Is it a classical thing to replace $d\, B_t$ by a Student instead of a Normal gaussian, in a O-U process?

Answer (score 1):

Try modelling samples every 20,000 ticks, instead of 2 hours (or any such number like that).  Markets are often less fat tailed in terms of the trade- or volume-clock.  See http://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-High-Frequency-Finance-Ramazan-Gen%C3%A7ay/dp/0122796713 and http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2034858